# Cocoa disable tabItem at index

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nstabviewcontroller

I have a `NSTabViewController` which has two `NSTabViewItem`. I want to disable second tab.

```
class MainTabViewController: NSTabViewController {

// Properties
var data : [String: AnyObject]?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tabItem = self.tabView.tabViewItem(at: 1)
    tabItem.isSelectable = true


   }

}
```

as `tabItem.isSelectable` is a get only property, how can I disable and enable`NSTabViewItem` item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the delegate for your tab view and implement `func tabView(NSTabView, shouldSelect: NSTabViewItem?)` method to return false if you need to disable a specific `NSTabViewItem`.